# How to convert Localtime to user seleted timezone in php

Tags: php

I want to convert the India time to user selected timezone in php. I used the following php code, but it showing some error

`Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (+13:40)'`

My php code

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-10-22 01:39:53 +5:30');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('+13:40'));
echo   $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But this code is working perfectly in phpfiddle.
**Working link here** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5vi2-r7t9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's likely a PHP version problem. From my tests it seems that PHP versions before 5.5.10 do not support the `+nn:nn` timezone format:

See https://3v4l.org/C8V2l

Try replacing it with a named timezone from the [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) or upgrade your PHP version.